# Smarty: what is the difference between templates_c and cache folder?

Tags: php, smarty, template-engine

There are two folders - `templates_c` and `cache` that are used when using Smarty with caching.

I have enabled caching and after that, both contain some sort of cache (IMHO same files) but still with some php, not pure HTML. However, just curious what is the difference in those folders? Where Smarty looks first when trying to locate relative cache file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`templates_c` used for compiled templates, but without the actual content, that can be dynamically inserted into them. On the other hand the `cache` folder is used for what you know as cached pages - the complete pages that served to user instead of re-compiling them each time.

Comment: Thanks. IMHO term "compiled" should be used in context of other  languages like C-based and java where you have to compile your sources into binary executables. I know PHP is implemented on C, so for sure, php scripts are compiled somewhere deep inside PHP. But as PHP developer you are never bored to see those compiled files. So, looking at files in template_c, I see they are just prepared PHP files with no smarty tags (already replaced and prepared). And the cache files are   prepared HTML (except some meta PHP code and several PHP tags ) files.

Comment: Actually I think "templates_c" is just a short from "templates_compiled", so they've tried to follow the convention you mentioned :)